# How should I implement an eclipse plugin to analyze source code and add markers to any errors it finds?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to make an eclipse plugin that takes in the name of a project and analyzes the code in any .java files in that project and adds markers (red squigglies underneath) to any errors according to a custom set of rules. For right now I'm just trying to figure out how to mark the source code by matching strings, I plan on adding a custom rule set later.

As a simple example if you wanted to mark any occurrence of of the String "Hello" in

```
public class helloWorld { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

How would you go about analyzing it and then marking the code inside the editor?

Comment: This question is very broad. I suggest you read up on the [Eclipse JDT Abstract Syntax Tree](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html) and then come back with a more detailed question.

Comment: Also https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Mark%20My%20Words/mark-my-words.html and the use of JFace Annotations directly shown in https://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_Text .